# Find the follwing limit if $f$ is differentiable

Tags: calculus

If $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$ and $f'(0) =2$, then find $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{2f(x) - 2f(2x)}{x}.$$

I don't know how to start, a hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hints:

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{2f(x)-2f(2x)}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{2f(x)-2f(0)+2f(0)-2f(2x)}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{2f(x)-2f(0)}{x}+\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2f(0)-2f(2x)}{x}=2f'(0)-4f'(0)$$

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple approach. Since $f'(0)=2$ it follows by definition of derivative that $$f(x) =f(0)+xf'(0)+xg(x)=f(0)+2x+xg(x)$$ where $g(x) \to 0$ as $x\to 0$. And then $$f(2x)=f(0)+4x+2xg(2x)$$ From these equations we get $$2f(x)-2f(2x)=-4x+2xg(x)-4xg(2x)$$ and hence $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2f(x)-2f(2x)}{x}=-4+2\lim_{x\to 0}g(x)-4\lim_{x\to 0}g(2x)=-4$$

Answer (score -1):

f'(0)=2 $$\\\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{2f(x)-2f(2x)}{x}=\frac{0}{0}$$so you can use l'hoptial rule 
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{2f(x)-2f(2x)}{x}=\\
2\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{f'(x)\times1-f'(2x)\times 2}{1}=\\
2\dfrac{f'(0)\times1-f'(0)\times 2}{1}=\\2(2-4)=-4$$

Comment: L'Hospital's Rule does not apply here because we don't know if $f$ is differentiable at points other than $x=0$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh :Note that ,I answered it according to "Find the follwing limit if ff is differentiable"!

Comment: Your approach requires continuous differentiability of $f$ at $0$. This is neither given in question nor in your answer. You should not try to assume more than what is provided in the question. The question only says that $f$ is differentiable at $0$.